# Display android asset image file in webview

Tags: javascript, android, css, dom

In Android webview I have js that adds a div on the right hand side of the margin(on webview), now this works fine when I add the div with background color.

This does not seem to work when want to add a background image on the div instead.

Here is my js that renders the div

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.style.width = "20px";
                    div.style.height = "20px";
                    div.style.position = "absolute";
                    div.style.top = yPos + "px";
                    div.style.right = "5px";
                    div.style.backgroundColor = col;
                    div.style.backgroundImage = "url(file:///android_asset/images/ic_menu_notes_pressed.png)";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

The background color loads fine, but no image is shown.
My image is located in /assets/images/ic_menu_notes_pressed.png

---

#### Update, using following solution () base64

**js file**

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.style.width = "50px";
img.alt = "Hello";
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

document.body.appendChild(img);

Answer (score 1):

Put your image (ic_menu_notes_pressed.png) in the asset folder and load url in web view like this

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html_string, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Now you can use like

```
 <img src="ic_menu_notes_pressed.png">
```

or

```
  <div style="backgroundImage =ic_menu_notes_pressed.png";> </div>
```

Comment: I ended up using the base 64 embedded image, as I only need to use this one image, my html file is loaded out of .epub and image exists in assets/images, when I reference the image file I get the epub path prepended to the filename like so, epub:///epub/279/OEBPS/Text/ic_menu_notes_pressed.png